# Laravel auth update user

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a page to edit the logged in users profile.

When I go to localhost.dev/users/1 the form shows.
I then enter new details and click Send.
The page reloads.
I then log out and enter the new password but it isn't recognised.
Looks like on submit the data isn't being stored in the DB.

Routes

```
Route::get('users/{user}',  ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@edit']);

Route::patch('users/{user}/update',  ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);
```

UserController - Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(User $user)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user->name = request('name');
        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));

        $user->save();

        return back();
    }
}
```

user/edit.blade.php - View

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('users.update', $user)}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('patch') }}

    <input type="text" name="name"  value="{{ $user->name }}" />

    <input type="email" name="email"  value="{{ $user->email }}" />

    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" />

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Route is work, enter data and click 'send' data isn't stored

Answer (score 0):

Laravel now uses this to encrypt passwords:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

Hash::make(request('password'));
```

So you may find that `bcrypt` is not working.